# restapi using mongoose and node.js on post,put, and delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

so i'm reviewing and practicing making rest api with node mongoose and express. I'm having problem making the post part of the api as I'm getting an error that I'm not sure how to fix. I'm kinda sure how to do the put and delete part. But if someone can show what that will look like. It will be great.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pokemon');

var pokemonSchema = {
    pokeid: Number,
    name:String,
    type:String,
    weight:String,
    height: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    summary: String

}

var Pokemon = mongoose.model('Pokemon', pokemonSchema);

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

//gets the all the pokemon
app.get('/pokemon', function(req, res) {
    Pokemon.find(function(err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
    });
});

//gets a specific pokemon
app.get('/pokemon/:id', function(req, res) {
    Pokemon.findOne({ _id: req.params.id},function (err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
    })
})


//create a new pokemon
app.post('/pokemon', function(req, res) {

    var pokemon = new Pokemon();

    pokemon.pokeid = req.body.pokeid;
    pokemon.name = req.body.name;
    pokemon.type = req.body.type;
    pokemon.weight = req.body.weight;
    pokemon.height = req.body.height;
    pokemon.summary = req.body.summary;

    //save pokemon
    pokemon.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'pokemon created'});
    });


})

//update the pokemon

app.put('/pokemon/:id', function(req, res) {


})

app.delete('/pokemon/:id', function(req, res) {

});
```

the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;pokeid&#39; of undefined
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/g62/pokemonsite/server/server.js:54:30
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at cors (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:179:7)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:229:17
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at originCallback (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:218:15)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:223:13
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at optionsCallback (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:9)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at corsMiddleware (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:209:7)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/home/g62/pokemonsite/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
```

I'm been trying to fix it but not sure how.

using postman for this
[image]

Comment: What are you getting in `req.body` in `POST` call?

Comment: i'm following this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4#want-more-meansetting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-applicationbuild-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4using-gruntjs-in-a-mean-stack-applicationauthenticate-a-node-api-with-tokens. The req.body is supposed to match up with the schema.

Comment: Add console and check the value of `req.body`. Also show us how you are requesting to `/pokemon` ?

Comment: using postman to check api and things

Comment: Have you checked value of `req.body`? Add a console for `req.body` and `pokemon` and check the values of both.

Comment: how do i do that exactly?

Comment: Just put  this line
console.log(req.body); above
 var pokemon = new Pokemon();
that will print if you are calling right `route`

Comment: okay,  i did it and got a error when starting the server ReferenceError: req is not defined

Comment: You have added it inside `function(req, res){` right?

Comment: I put it at the bottom of the code but changed it to in function. not sure what I'm looking for though.

Comment: Please add `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` to you code, you need `body-parser` midware.

Comment: already had var express and other stuff. didn't bother including in the question as the code already long.

Comment: We just want to know value for `req.body` is giving proper value or not. For that you have to add console.log() in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**req.body**

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By
>   default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing
>   middleware such as body-parser and multer.
>
> The following example shows how to use body-parsing middleware to
>   populate req.body.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

Please read the link: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a new pokemon
app.post('/pokemon', function(req, res) {

    var pokemon = new Pokemon({

    pokeid = req.body.pokeid;
    name = req.body.name;
    type = req.body.type;
    weight = req.body.weight;
    height = req.body.height;
    summary = req.body.summary;

});


    //save pokemon
    pokemon.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'pokemon created'});
    });


})
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit a post/put/delete request it will be better to use body-parser middleware.

for example delete any data (e.g. pokemon) from the data base you can follow this method.

including/require necessary libraries/modules.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var urlencode = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

now create a delete request on API...

```
router.delete('/pokemon/:id', urlencode, function(req, res, next){
     new Videos({id: req.body.id}).destroy().then(function(result){
        res.json(result.toJSON());
     }) 
});
```